# Left of '.getDrinkPrice' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++

This is a project from a c++ book I'm learning from.

I keep getting the error

```
"left of '.getDrinkPrice' must have class/struct/union"
```

I have tried fixing it but I just keep messing it up further. The visual studio error lists aren't too friendly for new users and this is really bothering me. I obviously don't want the code to be reposted fixed but I do want to be pointed in the right direction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

double wallet = 10.00;
int change;
bool isRunning;
bool isChoosing;
int userChoice;
double pricePaid;

class Soda {
private:
    string drinkName;
    double drinkPrice;
    int drinkAmt;

public:
    Soda() {
        drinkName;
        drinkPrice = .75;
        drinkAmt = 20;
    }

    void setDrinkName(string name) {
        drinkName = name;
    }

    string getDrinkName() {
        return drinkName;
    }

    void setDrinkPrice(double price) {
        drinkPrice = price;
    }

    double getDrinkPrice() {
        return drinkPrice;
    }

    void setDrinkAmt(int amt) {
        drinkAmt = amt;
    }

    void setNewDrinkAmount(int amt, int i) {
        drinkAmt = amt - i;
    }

    int getDrinkAmt() {
        return drinkAmt;
    }

};

// Declares classes
Soda * Cola = new Soda;
Soda * RootBeer = new Soda;
Soda * LemonLime = new Soda;
Soda * Grape = new Soda;
Soda * Cream = new Soda;
Soda *soda = new Soda;

static void init() {

// Pushes the Vending Machine data to the screen
    cout << "Drink Name: " << " " << "Drink Cost: " << " " << "Number in machine: \n";

    cout << *Cola->getDrinkName << " " << *Cola->getDrinkPrice << " " << *Cola->getDrinkAmt <<endl;

    cout << *RootBeer->getDrinkName << " " << *RootBeer->getDrinkPrice << " " << *RootBeer->getDrinkAmt << endl;

    cout << *LemonLime->getDrinkName << " " << *LemonLime->getDrinkPrice << " " << *LemonLime->getDrinkAmt << endl;

    cout << *Grape->getDrinkName << " " << *Grape->getDrinkPrice << " " << *Grape->getDrinkAmt << endl;

    cout << *Cream->getDrinkName << " " << *Cream->getDrinkPrice << " " << *Cream->getDrinkAmt << endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "You have $" << wallet << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void checkValidPurchase(Soda soda, double w, double p) {
    double priceOfDrink = soda.getDrinkPrice();
    int amountOfDrink = soda.getDrinkAmt;

    // If there are enough drinks are in the machine
    if (amountOfDrink > 0) {

        // If user has enough money
        if (w >= priceOfDrink) {

            // If amount paid is greater than drink price
            if (p > priceOfDrink) {

                // Calculate price and change
                w = w - p;
                double getChange = p - priceOfDrink;

                // Return Change
                cout << "Paid " << p << " returning " << getChange << endl;

                // Update amounts
                int j = soda.getDrinkAmt;
                soda.setNewDrinkAmount(j, 1);
                w = w + getChange;
            }

            // If amount paid is equal to drink price
            else if (p == priceOfDrink) {

                // Calculate price
                w = w - p;
                cout << "Paid " << p << endl;

                // Update amounts
                int j = soda.getDrinkAmt;
                soda.setNewDrinkAmount(j, 1);
            }

            // If amount paid is less than drink price
            else if (p < priceOfDrink) {

                // Prompt error and return to drink select
                cout << "You did not enter enough money, returning to drink select. \n";
                Sleep(3000);
            }
        }

        // If user does not have enough money
        else {
            cout << "Not enough money in wallet. \n";
            double amtNeeded = w + (w - priceOfDrink);
            cout << "You have: " << w << " Needed for purchase: " << amtNeeded << endl;
            Sleep(3000);
        }
    }

    // If there are not enough drinks in machine
    else {
        cout << "Not enough of " << soda.getDrinkName << " in machine. \n";
        Sleep(3000);
    }

}

void sodaMachine() {

    // Starts the drink select loop
    isChoosing = true;

    while (isChoosing) {

        // gets user input
        cout << "Enter the number of the soda you would like: \n";
        cout << "Or to quit, press escape \n";

        switch (userChoice) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Dispensing Cola \n";
            cout << "Cost is .75 \n";
            cin >> pricePaid;

            checkValidPurchase(*Cola, wallet, pricePaid);
            isChoosing = false;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Dispensing Root Beer \n";
            cout << "Cost is .75 \n";
            cin >> pricePaid;

            checkValidPurchase(*RootBeer, wallet, pricePaid);
            isChoosing = false;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "Dispensing Lemon Lime \n";
            cout << "Cost is .75 \n";
            cin >> pricePaid;

            checkValidPurchase(*LemonLime, wallet, pricePaid);
            isChoosing = false;
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "Dispensing Grape \n";
            cout << "Cost is .80 \n";
            cin >> pricePaid;

            checkValidPurchase(*Grape, wallet, pricePaid);
            isChoosing = false;
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "Dispensing Cream \n";
            cout << "Cost is .80 \n";
            cin >> pricePaid;

            checkValidPurchase(*Cream, wallet, pricePaid);
            isChoosing = false;
            break;

        case WM_CHAR:

            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
                cout << "Exiting program \n";
                isRunning = false;
                break;
            }

        default:
            isChoosing = false;
            break;
        }

    }
}

int main() {

    // Sets class values
    Cola->setDrinkName("1. Cola");
    RootBeer->setDrinkName("2. RootBeer");
    LemonLime->setDrinkName("3. LemonLime");
    Grape->setDrinkName("4. Grape");
    Grape->setDrinkPrice(.80);
    Cream->setDrinkName("5. Cream");
    Cream->setDrinkPrice(.80);

    isRunning = true;

    while (isRunning) {

        // Run Program
        init();
        sodaMachine();
        system("cls");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you dereferencing your pointer before calling the `getDrinkXXX` methods? For that matter, why don't you actually call the methods (ie. use `getDrinkXXX()`)? You probably want to do `Cola->getDrinkName()` instead of `*Cola->getDrinkName`.

Comment: It is vitally important that you learn to start with simple exercises and work up to complex ones. If you type in a program this big, at a level of complexity this far beyond your familiar range, it'll probably have bugs-- and even if you copied it perfectly from a perfectly correct source, you'll learn nothing.

Comment: Compared to `SYNTAX ERR`, Visual Studio's error messages are a godsend. Could be better, but the problem is the error message has to deal in generalities, so very often they can't explain exactly what you got wrong. Anyway, your syntax is pretty messed up and the compiler probably doesn't understand enough of what you are telling it to give you a good error message. Recommendation: write less code before trying to build and test.

Comment: And while I'm ranting like an old man, get rid of all those damn pointers! You don't need them and you aren't cleaning up after them. Only use a pointer if you have no other sane alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*Cola->getDrinkName` is not correct.
Use either `Cola->getDrinkName()` or `(*Cola).getDrinkName()` instead; same for all other calls of the same kind in your code.